# Self growing label in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, tableview

I am working with `Tableview` in `Objective C`.

I have 4 labels in a TableView cell. I want to expand the Comment Body label and Answer Body label according to the content size. How it is possible using AutoLayout. Please help me

How to set dynamic height of label as per content?

The ScreenShot of the `tableview` is given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Constrain**

Comment Body :- Top, Trailing, Bottom

Answer Body :-  Top, Trailing, Bottom

comment :- Center y to Comment Body, leading, Horizontal to Comment Body , Fix width

Answer :- Center y to Answer Body, leading, Horizontal to Answer Body, Fix width

`numberOfLine` 0 for both dynamic label

**Code**

Add Following code to `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear`

```
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80;
```

Note: Remove `heightForRow`

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint should be like,

`Comment` ->  top, leading(left side), fixed width, fixed height

`Answer` ->  top, leading, fixed width, fixed height

`Comment Body` ->  top, leading, trailing (right side), fixed height (**greater than or equal to some constant value**), bottom

`Answer Body` ->  top, leading, trailing, bottom

Make sure that number of lines for `comment body` and `answer body` must be `0`.

and you have to set estimatedrowheight and row height for your tableview like,

```
  self.yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;
  self.yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

OR

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      return 50;
  }

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```