# How to create a table whose height can be autoadjusted

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a tableview whose height is 70% of the screen sometimes I don't have enough rows to fill up all 70% then in that case there are some empty spaces with blank rows and it looks awkward.so if the height gets auto adjusted to the tablerows content then it'd be great but I couldn't find anything related to do this.

so how to do it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46439510/5461400

Comment: This is for row auto height..my doubt is about table as whole and its auto height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like below

- Take `IBOutlet` of height constraints of `UITableView`

And you will be find height of tableView based on your data/rows

```
tableView.contentSize.height
```

Now You need to change your height constraints based below condition

```
if  tableView.contentSize.height < UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height { // Instead of UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height, change as per your requirment

  yourTblHeightConstraints.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
else {
  yourTblHeightConstraints.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height // Instead of UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height, change here as you need
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: replace  self.view.layoutIfNeeded() with  self.view.setNeedsLayout()

Comment: If you write this code (with layoutIfNeeded) in a real application you will get exceptions sometimes.